# What is the meaning of the "callback=jQuery" query parameter in Http Request header?

Tags: jquery, http, http-headers

I'm trying to analysis a website login process.There exists a "callback=jQuery" in the GET request header I send to the server.Here is an example:

`callback=jQuery17100013734368553252607_1378108363139&username=...`

The number following `jQuery` varys every time.

So what does this mean exactly OR how to generate such numbers? Thank you!

Comment: it is used to over come same origin policy regarding requesting resources from a different domain using ajax

Comment: @ArunPJohny So generally how is the number `17100013734368553252607_1378108363139` generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Arun said...

What happens is that the server answer implements this callback with a 'function'...
Like this:..

```
jQuery17100013734368553252607_1378108363139('json_string_here')
```

and jquery generates this function, so it can be called:

```
function jQuery17100013734368553252607_1378108363139(string) {
   ...
}
```

so the answer calls this function... and you have access to the response...

Comment: Do you mean that `17100013734368553252607_1378108363139` is hard-coded?

Comment: no, jquery creates it, for every request, to avoid same function names for different ajax call's! this was just to explain waht is happening!

Comment: on client side yes! on server side, you have to bind it in your response, in PHP something like this: `echo $_GET['callback'] . '('data_here')';`